# WholeFileInputFormat with multiple files Input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can i use WholeFileInputFormat with many files as input?
Many files as one file...
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, String ...); doesnt seem to work properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "isSplittable" in your InputFormat to "false" so that the input file doesn't get split and get processed by just 1 mapper. One small suggestion though, you could give Sequence File a try. Combine multiple files, you are trying to process, into a single Sequence File and then process it. It would be more efficient as Sequence Files are already in key/value form.

Comment: I tried to pass 4 files, but it seems not to get it as a whole single file... I set "isSplittable"

Comment: How to combine the files? All these files i want to process as one is the result of another job....

Comment: what exactly is the requirement?processing one file as a whole or processing multiple files together?if your intention is just to club all the output files into one you could use "getMerge" utility for that.

Comment: i Have 4 files or more and i want to concate them all in one file and after to process it with WholeFileInputFormat

Comment: I cant understand how i can in a job to concate files in one big file... getMerge doesnt send it to local?

Comment: I have some files in seperate folders... i want all these files to merge them and to import the files in a mapper with the class WholeFileInputFormat.. thank you for your replies

Comment: so you want to first merge all these files into one and then send this one file to your mapper?or merging is possible after processing individual small files?

Comment: You wan just one mapper processing all the input files?

Comment: there is no out of the box feature which allows us to merge the files and simultaneously send them to a mapper as one single file. you need to write your own code for this. to start with you can use "MultipleInputs" class to feed each of these small files to a single mapper and then have just one reducer so that final output is a single file holding all the smaller files.

Comment: yes one mapper all the inputfiles... inputfiles may be in different folders

Comment: i found thishttp://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#concat%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path[]%29 but it is available only in newer versions.. can i use it in 1.0.4?

Comment: If you want to process multiple files together in a single map, you need to use CombineFileInputFormat. It will process multiplr files at one go